# insert row using sql depending on if listbox is empty

Tags: c#

If there are no more items in listbox, and the user clicks the 'next' button, I want the system to insert a row into the database... But nothing appears in the database. Can anyone help?

```
        string str = "";
        str = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();

        if (listBox2.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Production Completed");

            string clb = "";
            if (checkedListBox.Items.Count <= 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (str == "")
                    {
                        str = checkedListBox.Items[i].ToString();
                    }
                }
                    MAcon.Open();
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Insert into  Inventory([Product ID], [Order ID], Barcode, SubBarcode, [Completion Date]) values(@ProductID, @OrderID, @Barcode, @SubBarcode, @CompletionDate)", MAcon);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", ProductID.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderID", OrderID.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Barcode", BarcodeTxt.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompletionDate", Date.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubBarcode", clb);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    DialogResult start = MessageBox.Show("Production has begun", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    MAcon.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: `checkedListBox.Items.Count >= 0` instead of `checkedListBox.Items.Count <= 0`

Comment: you are checking count `<0` and then you are doing for loop , ` if (checkedListBox.Items.Count <= 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox.Items.Count; i++)
                {`not getting ti at all

Comment: It's unclear which list box you're referring to, but your loop is not going to run if checkedListBox.Items.Count <= 0.   Step through your code, and errors like this should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand Instead of 

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand
```

Same with `SqlConnection`

ALL `OleDb` change to `Sql`;

Make sure you `connection string` is for `SQL Server`;